# vscode error warning ejs dynamic element style

Tags: visual-studio-code, ejs

I have an element that should have dynamic style :

```
<div class="d-none" style="left: <%=i%>px; top: <%=i%>px;">
```

for style part **(style="left: <%=i%>px; top: <%=i%>px;")** vscode says

> at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected).

I installed ejs language support plugin but still error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a vscode bug and seems it will be fixed in next versions : [related github isssue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51118)